Torus as a mapping cone
Is it possible to write the torus as a mapping cone? I think about a map $f$ from the unit interval $I$ to the square $I\times I$ such that its mapping cone $Cf$ models the usual identification within a square but I am not sure how to put this formal.
So my question is about a map $f:X\to Y$ such that its mapping cone $C_f$ is homeomorphic to the torus $S^1\times S^1$.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I added an explicit question now, thanks.

Of course it is possible. Select an small open disk $D^2$ from the torus $T$, let $Y$ be $T\backslash D^2$, $X=S^1$ and $f$ sending $X$ to $S^1=\partial D^2 \subset Y$. The resulting mapping cone is then homeomorphic to $T$.

And there is nothing special about the torus here, the same proof works for every topological manifold.
